# How to Extract dll librarys from .exe file in ubuntu

Tags: 16.04, playonlinux

I'm trying to extract dll's from an .exe file by using PE parse. but i'm facing some problem with Parse, so can any alternate method is there to extract dll's from exe file.

Can anyone help i need as attached format:

[image]

Comment: You cannot extract DLLs from a binary. They are _shared libraries_ and only _references_ to them are stored in the binary. The DLL itself is a separate file.

Comment: Thanks for rply, So how to extract those references from exe file in ubuntu. And i need a format in, which i attached.

Comment: What's that exe file?

Comment: That is windows virus file. Actually i have to take those dll's for ransomeware analysis.

Comment: I just found an article [Extract an Embedded EXE or DLL using FileInsight | Mick's Mix](https://micksmix.wordpress.com/2012/12/30/extract-an-embedded-exe-or-dll-using-fileinsight/). Although I haven't tested it by myself but you can give it a try.